# TeX markdown needed on Meta

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, meta, tex

As seen in the recent [sandbox question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434/857), TeX markdown isn't enabled on Meta.

It should be.  It's needed for the sandbox, and we're likely to have questions on how to do something in TeX, TeX bug reports, TeX feature requests, and, after the feature is more familiar, questions which assume that TeX is enabled on Meta and try to use it.

I don't want to have to go over to Math.SE and try stuff on their meta (they have it enabled).  I don't think they'd like that much... :)

Test: \$\LaTeX\$

Comment: Wasn't sure how to tag it, so I covered my bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have enabled MathJax on this meta.

Answer (score 1):

We generally avoid this unless *absolutely* necessary because [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is a 500kb+ dependency on every page load for a new user.

Comment: Could you do that for a month while we get the hang of it, at least?

Comment: I understand your position, but does meta even get enough random first-time viewers to really worry about that? (Without looking at the logs) It seems like just a few people use meta.

Comment: @W5VO Perfect point!